# Newline after "Proof" in proof environment in amsthm package

Tags: latex

I'm writing a proof for a long theorem in LaTeX.The content of the proof is a long list of items.
My code is:

```
    \begin{proof}
     \begin{itemize}
      \item asd
      \item asd
     \end{itemize}
    \end{proof}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
proof * asd
   * asd
```

Is it possible to insert a newline  after the "proof" word to get something like:

```
proof 
   * asd
   * asd
```

\newline,\\ doesn't work inside the proof environment.
Maybe there is some other way to make it look better?

My latex distribution is texlive 2011

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `~` before `\begin{itemize}`.

Comment: Thank you! this works. I also  found one more dirty solution: to insert \item[] after begin{itemize} :D